# plotting with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot the attached image by `pgfplot`[image]

MWE (I have a problem in the `y-axis`):

```
\documentclass\[border=5pt\]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.13}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} \[  
  xlabel={$\langle \phi\rangle$}, 
  ylabel={$E$},
  axis x line= center,
  axis y line= center, %left, right, bottom, 
  xtick= \empty,
  ytick= \empty,
  xticklabel=\empty,
  yticklabel=\empty,
     \]   % axis lines=center
  \addplot\[mark=none,  red,   ultra thick\] {20 * x^2 + x^4 - 100};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}]
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  The function you plot is entirely positive but the graph you have is negative for some period.  The x-axis in your code is drawn at `y=1000` you can specify a `ymin` using `ymin=0` as an entry in the axis options which may be (closer to) the plot you want.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks a lot, it's the `ymin=0` which I have to add.

Comment: Voting to close, as the implied question is unlikely to help others, and OP indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: @DaiBowen, I edited it (I replaced `+10^3` by `-100` ). Now, the bottom part of the figure get suppressed !

Comment: @LlavDem try removing `ymin=0` if your plot now goes down to `-100`

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen This is a question I'm sure I've seen before (`pgfplots` not placing axis at origin sort of thing) and if not a dupe (I strongly suspect it is) I think does deserve an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.